# D7 - Organic Groups User Group Permissions when adding other Members

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups

I really am struggling to come to grips with this using OG-7.27...I have the standard **Drupal roles** (anon. user, authenticated user, administrator) as well as the standard **OG Roles** (non-member, member, administrator member) installed.

I want to allow all users in the *Drupal role of administrator* to create all groups, and for these users to empower certain *Drupal authenticated users* to manage content and add/remove users to/from it. Drupal authenticated users will be promoted to the OG Role of *administrator member* when the Drupal Admin user adds him/her to the group. The problem is that when I test this I see that this promoted user can see the ability to:

1. Block or Remove the Drupal Admin user (even though it actually does not seem to work)
2. Add other members to the group with the option to add them to the OG *administrator member* role.

I don't wish for either of these to happen. Below some screenshots:

**As seen by the Drupal Admin User:**
[image]

**As seen by the *OG* Administrator User:**
[image]

**Again as seen by the *OG* Administrator User when managing group members:**
[image]

Please may I ask your help as I'm not sure I've configured this properly. Yep, you guessed it...OG noob here. I did go through the videos on Modules Unravelled channel on YouTube, but I still don't get why this is not working?